# Windows 10 - Can't remove 'Account unknown' permissions on HKLM

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-registry, uac

This is an offshoot of [trying to fix UAC from re-enabling itself at logon after changing registry keys](https://superuser.com/questions/1337252/uac-keeps-resetting-on-windows10). I'm trying to remove all write permissions to the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` key, but I keep getting an unknown account that adds itself back to the list after removing it, which I suspect is the culprit.

I read somewhere that this is because of inherited permissions, so I went to the root `HKLM` to remove it from there, but it still persists.

This unknown account does not appear in the list of user accounts under 'Users and groups' or anywhere else. I've upgraded my Windows installation from 8 to 10, but even then shouldn't it show up in the list of users?

Is there a way to stop this behavior and get rid of the unknown account?

Comment: To be honest, removing all of the write permissions on the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` is essentially what my father used to call *"hunting roaches with a shotgun."*  It **will** get the job done, but the collateral damage is inevitably worse than the original problem.  Your operating system is destined to encounter numerous problems if you do that.

Comment: I agree with Run5k here - this is probably not the best approach. That said, if you want to identify *what* is writing, you should try to identify the SID (that is, the unique key attached to the presumably unnamed account). You should be ablt to [**read**](https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/controlling-registry-acl-permissions-with-powershell/) the SID with PowerShell. From there, you should try to fgure out why it's being written to, and, if needed, stop it at the source - rather than fiddling with permissions in a way that might cause "mysterious" breakage half a year later.

Answer (score 1):

Do not import anything but a previously exported registry, I tried that once and destroyed my ability to do anything at all. Only run a new setup. There needs to be a change to the security system and how it works there should only be security for the Microsoft stuff and nothing else. You need control of all interpreter or compiler programs as well as all server programs. It is best policy to blast the OS into some kind of ROM which cant be altered in any way but changing chips.

Answer (score 0):

Consider importing a healthy registry from other computer which uses the same system.

If it’s hard to import, try to execute in-place upgrade via a clean 1803 iso from Microsoft website. Then, system reset, keep my files.