# Is there any way to completely disable UAC on Windows 10 Home 1803 and later?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

Up until Windows 10 1803, it appears that it was possible to completely disable UAC by editing the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA

From carrying out some research, however, it appears that this approach no longer works. Rather than simply changing the slider within the UAC section of the Control Panel to "Never Notify" (which doesn't actually disable the framework completely), is there any other way of doing this on the Home edition of Windows 10?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I've used Windows 7 for many years without needing this enabled; I understand the security concerns of doing this, but am confident that I know what i'm doing. I also take regular system drive snapshots.

Comment: Did you see this answer?...https://superuser.com/a/1228837/40928

Comment: @moab - Thanks for this. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have any impact in 1803 and later.